# Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: Cors Network failure URL Scheme

Tags: firebase, express, swagger-ui

I trying to do a swagger documentation for an Express API and Firebase database, when I make request to my database in local with postman it work, but with the swagger interface I get this error:

> Failed to fetch.
> Possible Reasons:
>
> CORS
> Network Failure
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

For my documentation I use swagger-autogen and swagger-ui-express
there is a example for the login endpoint:

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: `http://localhost:${port}`,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Welcome" });
});

app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerFile, options));
```

```
swagger.js
const outputFile = "schemas/swagger.json";
const endpoints = \["routes/auth.js", "routes/menus.js"\];

const doc = {
info: {
version: "1.0.0",
title: "Menus API documentation",
description: "Documentation of MenusAPI",
termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/",
contact: {
email: "contact@toto.com",
},
license: {
name: "Apache 2.0",
url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html",
},
},
servers: \[
{
url: "https://localhost:8081/menusapi/api/v1/",
},
\],
host: "/",
consumes: \["application/json"\],
produces: \["application/json"\],
securityDefinitions: {
OAuth2: {
type: "oauth2",
flows: {
authorizationCode: {
authorizationUrl: process.env.AUTH_UTI,
tokenUrl: process.env.TOKEN_URI,
scopes: {
read: "Grants read access",
write: "Grants write access",
},
},
},
},
bearerAuth: {
type: "http",
scheme: "bearer",
bearerFormat: "JWT",
},
},
"@definitions": {
AddUser: userSchema.registration,
Login: userSchema.login,
Menus: menusSchema,
},
};

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpoints, doc).then(() =\> {
require("../app");
});
```

```
routes/auth.js
router.post("/login", auth.login);

controllers/auth_controller.js
exports.login = async (req, res) =\> {
/\* #swagger.tags = \['Auth'\]
\#swagger.description = 'Service to login';
\#swagger.summary = "Service to login a user to the app";
\#swagger.security = \[{
"OAuth2": \[
'read',
'write'
\]
}\]
\#swagger.responses\[200\] = {
description: 'Login sucess',
schema: {
"message": "Successfully connected!",
"jwt": "A very long token",
"refresh_jwt": "An other long token"
}
}
```

console error:

```
throw new Error(`${(0, validate_1.invalidArgumentMessage)(arg, desc)} Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value${fieldPathMessage}. ` +
                  ^
Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value
```

I looked everywhere but I really don't know what to do

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I've edited the message to include le log error